# How to find sum of array with n elements in accumulator architecture using assembly language, using looz instruction

Tags: assembly, processor, accumulator

How to find sum of array with n elements in accumulator architecture using assembly language, using the `looz` instruction

As an example

```
loadacc#10
storeacc0x80
```

like wise

I already create array as follow

```
loadacc #3
storeacc 0x80
loadacc #4
storeacc 0x60
loadacc #5
storeacc 0x50
loadacc #0x80
storeacc 0x45

loadacc #6
storeacc 0x65

loadacc 0x75
add &0x45   
storeacc 0x75
loadacc 0x45
add #1     

looz
loadacc 0x75
```

Comment: Do you have a link to documentation for this "accumulator architecture" toy ISA you're using?